# Windows Runtime Component (for Universal 8.1) error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I created a simple application that updates when we change timezones.
The application runs without errors in both the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator and real phone, but When in Windows 8.1 I get this error:

[image: Windows 8.1 Error]

This is my project (wrote with VS2015 for Windows Universal 8.1): 
[My Project Files](http://www.rodfile.com/9hjt95zauvrd)

source of Runtime Component:
[Source code](http://www.rodfile.com/c30j0vj0gt42)
If possible can you help solve this for Windows Universal 8.1 as this file is only for Windows Phone 8.1.

I'm sorry for bad English.

Comment: File not found ==> base class undefined ==> not a class or struct name.  I doubt anybody here can find that file for you.  Make sure the project is built and its .winmd file is in that directory.

Comment: Thanks. The source of file is:http://www.rodfile.com/c30j0vj0gt42    This is source of that. It's a Runtime Component for Windows PHone 8.1 only. I just make it for universal and copy codes. Can you make that for me for Windows Universal?

Comment: @Amin can you please post the error message next time instead of a screenshot

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2504 'XamlRenderingBackgroundTask' : base class undefined RuntimeComponent.Windows c:\users\borjian\desktop\app1\runtimecomponent\runtimecomponent.shared\apptileupdater.h 19

Comment: But do you think that this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx) this is not supported on Windows 8.x.

Comment: Thanks but this is only way that I found to create custom tile for windows phone. How can do it now? I want to convert xml to Image to use image for my custom tile. Is possible to help me?

Comment: Windows 8.x doesn't have a way to build a client-side tile from within a background task. You have to generate it while in the foreground, or from a remote server.